# persistence not working with Ebeans in Play Framework 2

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

If I use the method `Ebean.save(modelObject)` in one model object, it save its content into the respective database table, if I use this method again, the Ebeans try to save the save object again, generating duplicate primary key errors.

There is a way to persist data, not really insert data? I cannot found one method for that.

Comment: I'm the main author of Ebean ORM. Ebean.save(modelObject) should work with the second call executing a sql update - hard to say why that didn't work as expected without more information.

Answer (score 2):

For saving new object use:

```
myobj.save();
```

for updating use:

```
myobj.update(myobj.id);
```

Comment: hey for myobj.update(myobj.id); I'm getting this exception: Method threw 'org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException' exception. Detail Message: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [models.User]: No property 'id' found

Comment: Answer to my question: Clean the solution and rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

You can force update by explicitly specifying the properties you want to update. Say you want to update the *name* then you will do like:

```
Ebean.update(something, new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("name")));
```